# Why are the decks in Agricola called Komplex, Interactive and Easy?

Tags: agricola

Komplex - *presumably from the german for Complex, but in what way are they complex? More difficult to play or to be able to play them, less beneficial, or do they complicate the overall game?*

Interactive - *Given the Komplex and Easy names, you would expect this to be called Intermediate, as another named difficulty level. How are these cards any more interactive than any of the others? Is it to do with synergies?*

Easy - *same as question for Komplex, how are these actually any easier to play with than the others?*

I ask this because I've now played with all of the decks (including mixed decks) and haven't really noticed any difference in game difficulty. If anything, the excellent buffs included in the Komplex pack seemed to make gameplay easier...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My own thoughts:

**Komplex Deck** - Yes. The rules for all occupations and minor improvements are more complex than E-Deck. Some improvements are harder to play. For instance, the Plow(plow 3 fields a time) improvement can be played as a combo in `Plow and also Sow` but in Complex Deck, this is forbidden. But there are more bonus points can be collected via minors. More occupations can play additional round-action. Better oven(+5 points), better masion( +2 on stone rooms ).

**Interactive Deck** - There are some special minors that create additional actions allowing other players to play and the owner benefits with food, such as Tavern. Moreover, some occupations are `buyers` ( reed buyer, wood buyer etc.,) that can *hijack* other player's resource. More occupations are doing with other players instead of round-actions.

**Easy Deck** - All occupations and improvements are usually doing ONE particular action. And the prerequisite for them are not as hard/complex as Komplex.

In my opinion, I would not mix all these decks. I think some occupations of E-Deck/I-Deck are significantly powerful than K-Deck. For example, Fisherman, Backer, `Well builder(+Village Well + Water Carrier`, this combination is the most cost-efficiency food generator, I think) etc..

Comment: I have successfully mixed I and K but only with experienced players.